# Connecting to a remote database using RMySQL - access denied

Tags: mysql, rmysql

I am trying to connect to a remote mysql database by the following steps

1. `SSH` into their machine and keep the tunnel open
   then,
2. Using a SQL client (Sequel Pro) or `RMySQL` through `RStudio`
   Using the SQL client I can connect to their database and perform queries. However, using `RMySQL` when I try to connect via,

   ```
   mydb = dbConnect(dbDriver("MySQL"), user='uname', password='pwd', dbname='dbname', host='localhost',group='destination')
   ```

I am getting the following error,

> Error in .local(drv, ...) :    Failed to connect to database: Error:
>   Access denied for user 'uname'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the query forcing to be TCP by specifying port resolved the issue.

mydb = dbConnect(dbDriver("MySQL"), user='uname', password='pwd', dbname='dbname', host='127.0.0.1',port = port)

Answer (score 0):

Default port for mysql is 3306

```
install.packages("RMySQL")
library(RMySQL)
driver = dbDriver("MySQL");
connection = dbConnect(driver, user='user', password='password', dbname='db',host='host', port='3306');
query = dbGetQuery(connection, statement="SELECT * FROM your_table");
```

Comment: As far as I know, the argument 'port' must be an integer value